# Docker machine, Virtual machine on D: drive on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, docker

Is it somehow possible to store docker machine with "virtual machine disk" in D: drive because I don't have enough space on C: drive. I mean docker and VM is now using `C:\Users\MyName\.docker` or `\.VirtualBox` folders. Containers are downloaded and unpacked there and it consume really lot of space.

Is it possible to store it for example to `D:\vm`?

Is there some config in which I can change directory of created machines?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4ac564e2-ad6d-4d32-8cb4-7fea481738a4/how-to-change-docker-images-and-containers-location-with-windows-containers?forum=ws2016) it could be possible by add `daemon.json` file in to path `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config` as described in github issue tracker [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/185).

In the social technet answer the option to add is

```
{"graph": "D:\\ProgramData\\Docker"}
```

but as described in to github issue tracker they says on may 2018 that option is gonna to be superseded by this:

```
{ "data-root": "d:\docker" }
```

Anyway also the solution proposed in to previously answer are valid options.